# How to add fade animation while initializing slick slider dynamically

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, slick.js

I am using a vue js plugin for slick slider. It's https://github.com/staskjs/vue-slick. I am loading the slider dynamically using `v-for` loop. Here is how I am re initializing when changing image data.

```
watch: {
        sliderImage(){
          this.$refs.slick.destroy()
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$refs.slick.create()

          })
        }
    },
```

Actually I am using two buttons to switch between different sliders and I am changing image data `sliderImage` in my method. Thus my watcher destroy the previous slider and create again with new images which is fine. But when creating new slide it loads immediately without any smooth transitions effect. How can I achieve a smooth fade transition? 
Any idea would be really helpful.

**Edit**

My components looks like this

```
<slick ref="slick" :options="slickOptions">
 <div class="height-100%" v-for="m in sliderImage">
   <div :class="{'sliding':isSlide}">
         <img :src="'/uploads/'+m" alt="" @click="hideBottom">
        </div>
 </div>
</slick>
```

My methods that changes data

```
showEnt()
  {
      this.sliderImage=this.entImage;
  },
  showExt(){
    this.sliderImage=this.extImage;
  }
```

Comment: Add full html and js code for clear understanding

Comment: edited. You can see now